# Is it mandatory to implement AWS SQS with JMS in Java?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, amazon-sqs, long-polling

I am new to AWS SQS and I want to implement it in my project. My question is Can I implement SQS independently or Do I need to use SQS Java Messaging Library? Could you please help me on this? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not - JMS is not at all required.  Indeed, I would recommend against it as it is JMS 1.0 and doesn't take advantage of any of the JMS 2 code.

You can start with something as simple as creating a queue:

```
CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = new CreateQueueRequest("my-queue-name");
String queueUrl = amazonSQS.createQueue(createQueueRequest).getQueueUrl();
```

This queue can then have messages put into it and be read from.

The biggest difference is that SQS requires polling.  It is not event driven like the `onMessage` method in a `MessageListener`.  You can poll and receive up to 10 messages at a time.  This looks something like:

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl)
                  .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10)
                  .withWaitTimeSeconds(5);

List<Message> messages = amazonSQS.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();

for (Message message : messages) {
    // process each message
}
```

Having said that, you can have a thread do the reading and, if there is a message, send that to a JMS queue yourself if you'd like.  That's ultimately what the Amazon JMS/SQS library is doing.

Take a look at the [Java SQS examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-sqs.html) for more detail.

**EDIT**

To address the question posted in the comment, one way of handling SQS queues is to poll a particular SQS queue in a thread.  While you could poll multiple SQS queues it is a bit simpler in code to poll one.  And you will poll the SQS queue as long as your program is running.  If you stop polling it you will no longer receive any SQS messages.

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar for your answer and clarification that is JMS is event driven and SQS is poll driven. Does polling continuously points to queue like onMessage()? or we need to problematically handle it like getMessages() in infinite loop (while(true))? Could you please clarify this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AmirsohalShaikh - I believe I've clarified the answer to add the information you're requesting - let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar for your response. Yes, I got my questions answer. I was looking for is there any Active Listener is given by AWS SQS (like in JMS MessageListener) or we need to handle it programmatically. Now I am clear we need to create SQS Listener by our self by using polling. We can use our own logic for creating Active Listener like multi-threading or scheduler, etc.